# Package image not showing up in flutter web after deployed to Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I am working on a flutter web Project, I need to display some countries as tiles like below. The Flag Image is is displayed when I run them in release or debug mode, But after I deployed them to firebase, The image is not displayed, and not any errors are displaying while I was checking in debug mode.

I have tried building in html renderer also, it didn't help.

The image I'm trying to display is from this package,
https://pub.dev/packages/country_icons

Weirdly, The same widget is working good on another screen within the same application.

I have tried  importing the flag pngs to local and made them as assets, still I got the same output, Instead of the below widget I used ListTile with the leading flag, same behaviour.

This is when I run in debug/release mode
[image]

This is after I deployed the code into firebase.
[image]

pubspec.yaml below,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  country_icons: ^2.0.2
```

Below is my widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 3,
      child: Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.grey[600],
        elevation: 5,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Image(image: AssetImage('icons/flags/png/$code.png', package: 'country_icons')),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 3, child: Text(text)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a toLowerCase() method solved the problem, Turns out, fetching being case insensitive in local, but after deployed, the file names are behaving as case-sensitive.

```
CountryCard(
  text: e.name,
  code: e.code.toLowerCase(),
),
```